# RxAndroidBle - Different results when using CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES or CALLBACK_TYPE_FIRST_MATCH

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, rxandroidble

I'm not able to find my ble device when using `CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES` parameter, but when I change this parameter by `CALLBACK_TYPE_FIRST_MATCH` the result is as expected.
Unfortunately, `CALLBACK_TYPE_FIRST_MATCH` doesn't work with several phones.

```
scanDisposable = rxBleClient.scanBleDevices(
                ScanSettings.Builder()
                        .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
                        .setCallbackType(ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES)
                        .build(),
                ScanFilter.Builder()
                        .setServiceUuid(ParcelUuid(UUID_SERVICE))
                        .build()
                )
                ?.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                ?.doOnDispose { }
                ?.subscribe(Consumer { scanResult ->
                    Log.d("Scan Result", scanResult.bleDevice.name + " - " + scanResult.bleDevice.macAddress)
                },
                    Consumer<Throwable> { onScanFailure(it) })
```

Android Pixel is able to find the device with `CALLBACK_TYPE_FIRST_MATCH`, but can't with `CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES`.

Galaxy S5 Neo is able to find the device with `CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES`, and `CALLBACK_TYPE_FIRST_MATCH` send a `BleScanException.SCAN_FAILED_OUT_OF_HARDWARE_RESOURCES`.

Comment: From what you are writing maybe you could solve your problem by using both options (of course you need to start two separate scans) I am currently developing bluetooth app and I am facing similar problam as you. Sony xperia completely ignores advertising when set to CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES and it does it even without using RxAndroidBle, so I assume the problem is not in RxAndroidBle library.

Comment: Thanks, It helps a lot.

Comment: Have you find anything, that might solve the problem of no results with CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES settings? I'm trying to solve this problem for past week, no luck yet.

Comment: Running two scans simultaneously did the trick...
Not really happy with this solution but I think I don't have choice and it's work. As soon as I found my device, I dispose both scans.